# Definir intervalos de tiempo para realizar acciones

Tags: python, date, hilos

Estoy trabajando en un programa en Python para un proyecto, debo un trigger que consta de repetir una acción 3 veces en un intervalo de digamos 5 segundos, en caso de que si se realicen las 3 acciones se abrirá una condicional y se podrán ejecutar otras acciones, en caso de que no se realice la acción 3 veces o pase el tiempo el contador de segundos debería reiniciarse y el usuario debe comenzar de 0, como puedo hacer esto? Lo que he podido encontrar en internet no es de mucha ayuda, mencionando principalmente la función sleep() o hacer uso de threading
Ayuda pls

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Answer (score -1):

Hace tiempo yo también tuve ese problema y no pude resolverlo. Ahora lo he resuelto utilizando el módulo [threading](https://docs.python.org/es/3.8/library/threading.html). Un ejemplo sencillo sería el siguiente:

```
import threading  # También se puede utilizar time.sleep() pero siempre es preferible hacer el mínimo uso de él

paises = iter(('Madagascar', 'Mongolia', 'Puerto Rico'))
capitales = iter(('Antananarivo', 'Ulán Bator', 'San Juan'))

for i in range(0,3):
    try:
        # El timer llamará a la función print después de 5*i segundos y los args son lo que vas a imprimir
        timer=threading.Timer(5*i, print, args=(f'La capital de {next(paises)} es {next(capitales)}', ''))
        timer.start()
    except StopIteration:
        break
```

Si tu programa requiere de inputs u otro tipo de eventos que requieren la interacción con el usuario podrías aprender del código que se encuentra más abajo (me he complicado un poco la vida en el código pero, por lo menos, he podido aprender de él y espero que más gente también pueda).

```
import threading, os

threads = []

paises = iter(('Madagascar', 'Mongolia', 'Puerto Rico'))
capitales = iter(('Antananarivo', 'Ulan Bator', 'San Juan'))

class Threads(threading.Thread):
    '''Clase que hereda threading.Thread'''
    def __init__(self, tiempo: int, pais: str, capital: str):
        self.event=threading.Event()  # Permite esperar <tiempo> segundos de forma paralela
                                      # e independiente al hilo sin intervenir e inhabilitar el input
        self.tiempo = tiempo
        self.pais = pais
        self.capital = capital
        self.t=threading.Thread(target=self.pedir_input)

    def pedir_input(self):
        '''Pide la capital del país y establece el flag del evento a True en el caso de que
    la respuesta sea correcta. Si no lo es, volverá a preguntar'''
        user_input = input(f"Capital de {self.pais}: ").lower().title()
        if user_input==self.capital:
            return self.event.set()
        else:
            self.pedir_input()

    def contar(self):
        '''Espera a que pase el tiempo en segundos, establecido al crear la instancia, y
    después saldremos del programa de forma bruta si no se ha introducido la respuesta
    correcta'''
        self.event.wait(self.tiempo)
        if not(self.event.is_set()):
            os.abort()

    def start_thread(self):
        '''Comienza el hilo y llama a la función <contar>. La función <join> espera a que el
    hilo termine para comenzar el siguiente, por lo que, en caso de que aciertes la
    capital saltará al siguiente hilo y pasará a la siguiente pregunta automáticamente sin
    comprobar si el flag del evento está activado o no'''
        self.t.start()
        self.contar()
        self.t.join()
        # Cambia esto si quieres esperar 5 segundos

while True:
    try:
        # Crea intancias de la clase y añade a una lista
        t=Threads(10, next(paises), next(capitales))
        threads.append(t)
    except StopIteration:
        # Cuando ya no quedan más elementos en el iterador sale del bucle
        break

for thread in threads:
    thread.start_thread()
```